# Cant pass activity Context

Tags: android, android-context

Hello I'm trying to use object from one of my libaries, but I can't pass my corrent context.

The constructor is:

```
public AmbilWarnaDialog(final Context context, int color, OnAmbilWarnaListener listener)
```

And in my class I use this for the constructor:

```
AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = AmbilWarnaDialog(this, initialColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener()
                     {

                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int[] color) {
                        // color is the color selected by the user.
                }

                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                        // cancel was selected by the user
                }
            });
```

I get this error:

```
The method AmbilWarnaDialog(Settings, int, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener(){}) is undefined for the type Settings
```

I also tried getApplicationContex() and Settings.this and it's not working.

My imports are:

```
import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog;
import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaKotak;
import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener;
```

Comment: What's is your this class 's declear ?

Comment: Post your settings class plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a constructor directly, to instantiate a class use the `new` keyword like this:

```
AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, initialColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener() { ...
```

Comment: yea... i fill do dumb :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Context context;

private methodName(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

call method in Activity:

```
    methodName(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this method somewhere inside the Settings class (I am assuming Settings doesn't extend Context). You might be doing something like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Context {

public myMethod(){

    new Settings(){

// the keyword this references to the Settings object instance, not MyClass object instance 
// to reference Context use MyClass.this
// like Henry says below, make sure you use the new keyword to initialize objects
AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(MyClass.this, initialColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {...}

       }
    }
```

}